# MQ7.h: No such file or directory

Tags: arduino-ide, library

Using ESP32 I'm making air pollution quality meter. For that I need MQ7.h library which is of version 1.0.4 MQUnified sensor library, which supports all sensors.

I am using MQ7 carbon monoxide sensor... but that shows error `no such file MQ7...`.

The link for library I will share with you [..github.com/miguel5612/MQSensorsLib..](https://github.com/miguel5612/MQSensorsLib....this).. This link has "mqunified" for all sensors. I just need it to support my code which have written for MQ7:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "MQ7.h"
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels
// Declaration for SSD1306 display connected using software SPI (default case):
#define OLED_MOSI   13
#define OLED_CLK   14
#define OLED_DC    12
#define OLED_CS    15
#define OLED_RESET 27
#define WIFI_ssid "rtpl1"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "startupindia007"
#define TOKEN "yXrewssGkRD8jgjPqW70"
#define MQ135 35 
#define MQ135_DEFAULTPPM 392 //default ppm of CO2 for calibration
#define MQ135_DEFAULTRO 41763 //default Ro for MQ135_DEFAULTPPM ppm of CO2
#define MQ135_SCALINGFACTOR 116.6020682 //CO2 gas value
#define MQ135_EXPONENT -2.769034857 //CO2 gas value
#define MQ135_MAXRSRO 2.428 //for CO2
#define MQ135_MINRSRO 0.358 //for CO2
#define MQ135_PULLDOWNRES 5000
#define ADC_REFRES 1024
uint16_t mq135_a ;
MQ7 mq7(34,3.3);
char thingsboardServer[]="demo.thingsboard.io";
String temperature, humidity, line, dust, mq135, mq7_CO;
float pm;
String latitude = "18.5457" , longitude = "73.7847";
int measurePin =  36;
int ledPower = 3;
int samplingTime = 280;
int deltaTime = 40;
int sleepTime = 9680;
float voMeasured = 0;
float calcVoltage = 0;
float dustDensity = 0;
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);
WiFiClient wifiClient;
// Initialize DHT sensor.
PubSubClient client(wifiClient);
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;
unsigned long lastSend;
StaticJsonDocument<200> jsonBuffer;

void getPPMData()
{
  mq135_a = analogRead(MQ135);
  long res = adc_getresistence(mq135_a, MQ135_PULLDOWNRES);
  long mq135_ro = mq135_getro(res, MQ135_DEFAULTPPM);
  double d = mq135_getppm(res, MQ135_DEFAULTRO);
  int accStatus=0;
  int reading=analogRead(32);
  Serial.println(reading);
  float t ;
  t=((reading*3.3*10)/4095);
  digitalWrite(ledPower,LOW); // power on the LED
  delayMicroseconds(samplingTime);
  voMeasured = analogRead(measurePin); // read the dust value
  delayMicroseconds(deltaTime);
  digitalWrite(ledPower,HIGH); // turn the LED off
  delayMicroseconds(sleepTime);
  // 0 - 3.3V mapped to 0 - 1023 integer values
  // recover voltage
  calcVoltage = voMeasured * (3.3 / 1024);
  dustDensity = 241.708 * calcVoltage - 0.1;
  dust = String(dustDensity);
  temperature = String(t);
  mq135 = String(d);
  mq7_CO = String(mq7.getPPM());
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1); // Draw 2X-scale text
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.print(F("CO2 PPM - "));
  display.println(mq135);
  display.print(F("CO PPM - "));
  display.println(mq7_CO);
  display.print(F("PM2.5 PPM - "));
  display.println(dust);
  display.print(F("TEMP - "));
  display.println(temperature);
  // Prepare a JSON payload string
  String payload1 = "{";
  payload1 += "\"temperature\":"; payload1 += temperature; payload1 += ",";
  payload1 += "\"humidity\":"; payload1 += humidity; payload1 += ",";
  payload1 += "\"CO2 PPM\":"; payload1+= mq135; payload1 += ",";
  payload1 += "\"CO PPM\":"; payload1 += mq7_CO; payload1 += ",";
  payload1 += "\"PM2.5 PPM\":"; payload1 += dust;
  payload1 += "}";
  // Send payload
  char telemetry1[100];
  payload1.toCharArray( telemetry1, 100);
  client.publish( "v1/devices/me/telemetry", telemetry1 );
  String payload2 = "{";
  payload2 += "\"latitude\":"; payload2 += latitude; payload2 += ",";
  payload2 += "\"longitude\":"; payload2 += longitude;
  payload2 += "}";
  char telemetry2[100];
  payload2.toCharArray( telemetry2, 100);
  client.publish( "v1/devices/me/telemetry", telemetry2 ); 
  display.print(F("Payload Sent to Thingsbaord"));
  display.display();
  Serial.println( telemetry1 );
}

void InitWiFi()
{
  Serial.println("Connecting to AP ...");
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_ssid, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1); // Draw 2X-scale text
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(10, 0);
  display.println(F("Connecting to AP"));
  // attempt to connect to WiFi network
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    display.print(F("."));
    display.display();      // Show initial text
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  display.clearDisplay();
  display.setTextSize(1); // Draw 2X-scale text
  display.setTextColor(WHITE);
  display.setCursor(0, 0);
  display.println(F("Connected to AP"));
  Serial.println("Connected to AP");
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  display.clearDisplay();
  while (!client.connected()) {
    status = WiFi.status();
    if ( status != WL_CONNECTED) {
      WiFi.begin(WIFI_ssid, WIFI_PASSWORD);
      display.setTextSize(1); // Draw 2X-scale text
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0, 0);
      display.println(F("Connecting to AP"));
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
        display.print(F("."));
        display.display();
      }
      display.clearDisplay();
      display.setTextSize(1); // Draw 2X-scale text
      display.setTextColor(WHITE);
      display.setCursor(0, 0);
      Serial.println("Connected to AP");
      display.println(F("Connected to AP"));
      display.display();
    }
    display.clearDisplay();
    display.setTextSize(1); // Draw 2X-scale text
    display.setTextColor(WHITE);
    display.setCursor(0, 0);
    Serial.print("Connecting to ThingsBoard node ...");
    display.print(F("Connecting to ThingsBoard node ..."));
    // Attempt to connect (clientId, username, password)
    if ( client.connect("ESP32 Demo Device", TOKEN, NULL) ) {
      Serial.println( "[DONE]" );
      display.println(F("Connected to Thingsboard node"));
      display.display(); 
    } 
    else {
      Serial.print( "[FAILED] [ rc = " );
      display.print(F("Connection failed - "));
      display.println(client.state());
      Serial.print( client.state() );
      Serial.println( " : retrying in 5 seconds]" );
      display.print(F(": retrying in 5 seconds"));
      display.display();
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay( 5000 ):
    }
  }
}

/*
 * get the calibrated ro based upon read resistance, and a know ppm
 */
long mq135_getro(long resvalue, double ppm) {
  return (long)(resvalue * exp( log(MQ135_SCALINGFACTOR/ppm) / MQ135_EXPONENT ));
}

/*
 * get the ppm concentration
 */
double mq135_getppm(long resvalue, long ro) {
  double ret = 0;
  double validinterval = 0;
  validinterval = resvalue/(double)ro;
  if(validinterval<MQ135_MAXRSRO && validinterval>MQ135_MINRSRO) {
    ret = (double)MQ135_SCALINGFACTOR * pow( ((double)resvalue/ro), MQ135_EXPONENT);
  }
  return ret;
}

/*
 * convert an adc value to a resistence value
 */
long adc_getresistence(uint16_t adcread, uint16_t adcbalanceresistor)
{
  if(adcread == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  else{
    return (long)((long)(ADC_REFRES*(long)adcbalanceresistor)/adcread-(long)adcbalanceresistor);
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if(!display.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC)) {
    Serial.println(F("SSD1306 allocation failed"));
    for(;;); // Don't proceed, loop forever
  }
  Serial1.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, rxPin, txPin);  //UART for pulse sensor Interfacing with Arduino
  //dht.begin();
  delay(10);
  InitWiFi();
  client.setServer( thingsboardServer, 1883 );
  display.println(F(thingsboardServer));
  display.display(); 
  delay(100);
  // Serial.println(thingsboardServer);
  lastSend = 0;
  pinMode(MQ135, INPUT);
  analogReadResolution(10);
  pinMode(ledPower,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(measurePin,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if ( !client.connected() ) {
    reconnect();
  }
  if ( millis() - lastSend > 500 ) { // Update and send only after 1 seconds
    getPPMData();
    lastSend = millis();
  }
  client.loop();
}
```

Comment: please describe what you are trying to do ... also add the complete error message

Comment: Using ESP32  I m making air pollution quality meter. For that I need MQ7.h library which is of version 1.0.4 MQUnified sensor library. which supports all sensors. I am using MQ7 carbon monoxide sensor...but that shows error no such file MQ7....the link for library I will share with you ..https://github.com/miguel5612/MQSensorsLib....this link has mqunified fr all sensors ..I just need it to support my code which have written for MQ7

Comment: Please don't put additional information in a comment. You can [edit] your question, for example by the link on the left below your question -- I did this for you just now. And, please, take the [tour] and learn [ask].

Comment: Did you install the library? If yes, how?

Comment: yes i installed in arduino IDE